# What kind of connector is this, or where can I get it?

Tags: refrigerator, connectors

Does anyone know what kind of connector this is? I have to change the power supply cord on a mini fridge and need the same 2 prong connector that plugs into the circuit board. Its the size of my thumb nail maybe half and inch wide.

[image]

Comment: You don't have the option of reusing this one?  Cut it off and then splice the wires to the new power supply.

Answer (score 2):

You can find that connector at www.mouser.com in their connector search tool. You will need to carefully measure the pin to pin spacing of that connector to be able to locate the correct part. Some connectors are using inch dimensions while others use millimeter dimensions so be prepared to measure and do some conversions if necessary.

Be aware that the type of connector that you have shown is just a nylon housing and the contacts are separately crimped onto the wires in the power cord. The each contact is pressed into its appropriate slot in the nylon housing.

Be aware that to properly terminate the wires with the crimp on terminals it is necessary to have the proper tool. Those crimp contacts offer minimal strain relief as it is and improperly applied contacts could let the wire pull out of the contact and lead to a very dangerous situation. A properly crimped terminal will have two sections, one which crimps around the copper wire and the other that crimps around the wire insulation. The insulation crimp will not work properly if the insulation is too small or large of diameter for the contact. It is also not at all advisable to try to solder the wires to the terminals.